# IE issue on dynamically setting the image

Tags: java, javascript, html, css, internet-explorer

I have an xhtml file where I dynamically set the image's src using a bean.

```
<h1
  class="logo"
  style="background-image: url(#{mainMenuNavigationBean.headerImage});">
```

and my method returns something like:

```
return "/resources/images/header/logo.png";
```

This works perfectly in Chrome but not in IE (it puts `background-image: none;`).

Do you see why?

**UPDATED**: The code is fine...suddenly started to work...

Comment: Probably caching somewhere...

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `..` before the path. like:

`return "../resources/images/header/logo.png";`